# In Tensorflow, How do I generate a range given an array that determines the bounds?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a Tensor that looks like T=Tensor([100, 400]) as well as a separate number N=5. I want to generate a new Tensor([96, 97, 98, 99, 100], [396, 397, 398, 399, 400]) formed by taking the range [value - N + 1, value] for each value in T.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution to this is to do `range = tf.reshape(T, [2, 1]) - tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(N), [2]), [2, -1])`.